# Error creating new method of nested resources

Tags: ruby, nested, resources

I have my resources:

```
  resources :flows do
    resources :fmodules
  end
```

the new method in fmodules controller:

```
# /flows/1/fmodules/new
def new
    @flow = Flow.find(params[:flow_id])
    @fmodule = @flow.fmodules.build
end
```

the models:

```
class Flow < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :fmodules, dependent: :destroy
    validates :code, presence: true, length: { maximum: 5 }
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

---

```
class Fmodule < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :flow
end
```

When i try to go at `/flows/1/fmodules/new` ruby says `unknown attribute 'flow_id' for Fmodule.`

I dont know what is wrong

Here is the migration of Fmodel in addition

```
class CreateFmodules < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :fmodules do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.string :name
      t.string :f_code

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :fmodules, :flows, column: :f_code
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please post the source code of `Fmodule` model?

Comment: What you mean?, i just have that in the Fmodule model.

Comment: Did you mean that?, I added the migration of Fmodel.

Comment: thanks! I haven't notice `Fmodule` code at all, but looking at migration was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is that you don't have a `flow_id` in your `fmodules` table. In rails, by convention the foreign key is build automatically inferring column name from an argument you pass to `belongs_to`. That's why rails think that foreign key for `flows` table is `flow_id` and it raises exception not finding it. You can overwrite the default with `foreign_key` option like the following

```
class Fmodule < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :flow, foreign_key: : f_code
end
```